# How do I encrypyt a response/request to a WebService ASMX?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, asmx

Here's my little web service demo:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)] 
public class ServicePrueba : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
    public int SayHello()
    {
        int counter;
        if (Context.Session == null)
        {
            counter = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            int tmpCounter = Convert.ToInt32(Context.Session["Counter"]);
            counter = tmpCounter + 1;
        }

        Context.Session["Counter"] = counter;
        return counter;
    }
}
```

And here's how I invoke it via a Console client application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServicePrueba serviceProxy = new ServicePrueba();

        /*Set the cookie container on the proxy.*/
        var cookies = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
        serviceProxy.CookieContainer = cookies;

        Console.WriteLine(serviceProxy.SayHello());
        Console.ReadKey();

        Console.WriteLine(serviceProxy.SayHello());
        Console.ReadKey();

        Console.WriteLine(serviceProxy.SayHello());
        Console.ReadKey();

        Console.WriteLine(serviceProxy.SayHello());
        Console.ReadKey();

        Console.WriteLine(serviceProxy.SayHello());
        Console.ReadKey();

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

My question is, the information that coming and going through the wire is in plain text no? (Is there a way to see what this data look like?)

How can I protect this sensitive information from prying eyes? I want to simply encrypt the message so it's gibberish when it's through the wire.

Comment: There was a similar question which provides quite useful answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448/encryption-in-c-sharp-web-services
But i think the most simple way is just using https

Answer (score 3):

You should use HTTPS. Hosting it over an HTTPS connection will solve this issue.

Comment: So if I use SSL in order to use HTTPS, nobody can fetch this information?

Comment: Correct. over SSL, everything potentially sensitive is encrypted. The only thing that might be considered sensitive is the destination server. So they would know who you are connecting to, but can't theoretically get any additional information than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the traffic via a packet sniffing tool like http://www.wireshark.org/download.html to analyze the packets. I'm pretty positive its not very useful .